# How to check if an image is "JPEG 2000" in Python?

Tags: python, image, jpeg, jpeg2000

How to check if an image file is `JPEG 2000` in Python?

If possible, without installing a heavy image library.

Comment: How is the image stored? Is it a file or something else?

Comment: It's a file, Michael. I've updated the question. Thanks.

Comment: Great, then I think my answer below works. Can you try it out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is stored as a file, you can check if it starts with the JPEG 2000 magic number, `00 00 00 0C 6A 50 20 20 0D 0A 87 0A` or `FF 4F FF 51`. Just like this:

```
with open('image.jp2', 'rb') as file:
    magic = file.read(12)
    if magic == b'\x00\x00\x00\x0C\x6A\x50\x20\x20\x0D\x0A\x87\x0A' or magic[:4] == b'\xFF\x4F\xFF\x51':
        print('File is JPEG 2000')
    else:
        print('File is not JPEG 2000')
```

If the image is not stored as a file, then you can easily adapt this code. All you need to do is check if the first 12 or 4 bytes match the magic number.

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work, Michael. For my JPEG 2000 image, `magic` is `b'\xffO\xffQ\x00/\x00\x00\x00\x00\x04\x10'`

Comment: @Marcel Oops, I forgot that JPEG 2000 images actually have two magic numbers. I've updated my answer so it should work now. The second magic number is actually only 4 bytes, so in your case the image's magic number is just `b'\xffO\xffQ'`. Thanks for the good catch!